# Obfuscation of Flutter Module Within An Existing Native App

Tags: android, flutter, dart, obfuscation

Right now we have a native application that had been launched to production. We want to use flutter but we don't want to rewrite the entire app, so we plan to use flutter for the upcoming new features and embed it as a module into the native app.

We have experienced some success following this guide:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app

But one thing that we haven't figured out is how to leverage the obfuscation feature that flutter offered. I have read this guide:
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate

but it mentioned nothing on how we can apply it to a hybrid app. Reading the log of the release build though, it seems that the obfuscation has been applied somehow since I see something like "flutterR8". Yet I don't know of any way how I can verify it.

One more thing, the documentation mentioned "--split-debug-info" which should print out some kind of symbol mapping to re-trace the obfuscated stack trace, I wonder where can I find the file if I'm using the hybrid approach?

Thanks.